# Non-trivially intersecting summands implies the space can be decomposed as the intersection of the original summands?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, direct-sum

Suppose that for some finite-dimensional vector space $V$, we have found two different decompositions:

$$V = \bigoplus_{k ∈ \mathbb Z} W_k = \bigoplus_{\ell ∈ \mathbb Z} U_\ell
$$

Now assume further that at least some of these summands intersect nontrivially. Does that mean we can write

$$V = \bigoplus_{(k,\ell) ∈ \mathbb{Z}^2} W_k \cap U_\ell    
$$?

If not, would the fact that all the summands are actually eigenspaces of commuting linear operators with eigenvalues indexed by $k, \ell$ help?

Comment: Just a remark: if $V$ is finite dimensional, then almost all $W_k$ and $U_\ell$ are zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $W_1 = \langle (1,0,0) \rangle, W_2 = \langle (0,1,0)\rangle, W_3 = \langle (0,0,1) \rangle$ and $U_1 = \langle (1,1,0) \rangle, U_2 = \langle (1,-1,0) \rangle, U_3 = \langle (0,0,1) \rangle$ as subspaces of $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: Not that I know of. In general given subspaces $A,B,C$ we have $A \cap B \oplus A \cap C \subset A \cap (B \oplus C)$ but the equality need not hold.

Comment: Yes, but in my case I had *assumed* that some summands intersected non-trivially. So this is not a counterexample.

Comment: Indeed, but can "embed" the former into operators in a larger space, e.g. $\mathbb R^3$ as diagonal matrices $\begin{pmatrix} T & 0 \\ 0 & I\end{pmatrix}$. That yields your desired counterexample, I think.

Comment: Concretely, the subspaces now given are eigenspaces for $I_3$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0\\1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ (viewed as linear transformations) respectively; and $W_3 = U_3$ have non trivial intersection.

Comment: Unfortunately, I see now. It must be a peculiarity of my case (I'm studying the representations of SU(3)).

Comment: Maybe if all intersections are non-trivial, then it works (if I had to guess I would guess that it does not, but I haven't thought about it)